# Exclude Specific String Within Regex/gsub

Tags: r, regex

I am able to remove everything between "<>" and "</>" using:

```
gsub("(<[^>]*>)","",abc)
```

I do not work with regex and can't figure out how to ignore a specific string.

My goal is to make a function where a user can supply values to ignore (i.e., ""), and then remove all values between "<>" or "</>" besides the ignored values.

```
character_vector <- c("<br>Hello</br>", "I want to keep this <important text>")

character_vector <- gsub("(<[^>]*>)","",character_vector)
```

Current Output:

```
[1] "Hello"                "I want to keep this "
```

Ideal Output:

```
[1] "Hello"                "I want to keep this <important text>"
```

Comment: It is done with a lookahead and a PCRE regex: `gsub("(<(?!important text>)[^>]*>)","",abc, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Deleted my comment... you still rule, but what if I wanted to supply multiple arguments to `<important text>`? The function I am looking to build would concatenate user-supplied values.

Comment: `gsub("(<(?!(?:text1|text2|textN)>)[^>]*>)","",abc, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect. thank you!

Comment: But there is a catch: will there be special chars in the strings to exclude? Like `(`, `[`, `?`, `+`? If you do not have control over what comes into the alternation, these may stop the code from working correctly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think that is possible but not likely, though I am definitely open to any suggestions you have to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
character_vector <- c("<br>Hello</br>", "I want to keep this <important text> and <string?>")
exclude <- c("important text", "string?")
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
gsub(paste0("<(?!(?:", paste(regex.escape(exclude), collapse="|"), ")>)[^>]*>"), "", character_vector, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Hello"                                             
##    [2] "I want to keep this <important text> and <string?>"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/coFhIj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s0tPHD/1). The `<(?!(?:important text|string\?)>)[^>]*>` regex matches

- `<` -  a `<` char
- `(?!(?:important text|string\?)>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `important text` or `string?` followed with a `>` char immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

The `regex.escape` function is necessary to escape any special char (`]`, `[`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `*`, `^`, `$`, `|`, `\`, `?`, `.`) that comes in the `exclude` character vector items.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great.

Comment: @Matt That is a regex that will allow exceptions that fully match `<...>`. If you want to exclude them as partial strings, you may either replace `")>)[^>]*>"` with `"))[^>]*>"` (that will exclude them only if they are at the beginning, right after `<`), or that and `"<(?!(?:"` replaced to `"<(?![^>]*(?:"`, to exclude `<...>` where `exclude` items appear anywhere in between `<...>`.